# Is this animation possible on an iPhone/iPodTouch?

Tags: iphone, animation, xcode4

Is this sort of animation possible on an iPhone/iPodTouch?  If yes, would it cause the app to slow down to a crawl?: an animated character would "liquefy" (become like a liquid--liquid mercury, etc.) and flow about the screen, in between and around the various buttons and field areas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds far outside the scope of Core Animation. You'd have to use OpenGL for something with that level of complexity--but yes, I do believe that's within the hardware's capabilities (depending on exactly what you mean.) Take a look at games like Infinity Blade or Rage to see what an iPhone's hardware is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Not with any standard protocols.  You could probably work up some totally custom thing but it would not be a trivial task.